# Reverse a linked list in java

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8, linked-list

I was reading the solution to reverse a linked list. It mentions to use swapping the links but I can't get an intuition as how author have come up with previous and next pointer approach. It feels like I have to memorize this order. Can some one give me the intuition of the below piece of code.

```
public static <T> void reverse(SinglyLinkedList<T> list){
    SinglyLinkedList<T>.Node previous = null; //To keep track of the previous element, will be used in swapping links
            SinglyLinkedList<T>.Node current = list.headNode; //firstElement
            SinglyLinkedList<T>.Node next = null;

            //While Traversing the list, swap links
            while (current != null) {
                    next = current.nextNode;
                    current.nextNode = previous;
                    previous = current;
                    current = next;
            }
            //Linking Head Node with the new First Element
            list.headNode = previous;
    }
```

Comment: Probably the best way to understand this is to step through the code with a debugger for a small list so that you can see what's happening step by step. Or maybe even physically draw the algorithm at each step (again, for a small list).

Answer (score 2):

It may help to visualise this with an example input. Let's say we have a list with three nodes with 1, 2, and 3 as values, then at the start of the loop we have this state:

```
previous: null
next: null

         current
           ↓
      ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────────┐
      │ data: 1    │   │ data: 2    │   │ data: 3        │
      │ nextNode: ───► │ nextNode: ───► │ nextNode: null │
      └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────────┘
             ▲
 ┌───────────│─┐
 │ headNode: ┘ │
 └─────────────┘
        ↑
       list
```

After the first assignment in the loop body, we can understand that `previous` points to the node *before* `current` (if any) and `next` to the node *after* `current` (if any). Although not really accurate, it helps to visualise `null` as if it is a virtual node. So we may picture that as follows:

```
previous  current            next
   ↓         ↓                ↓
        ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
        │ data: 1    │   │ data: 2    │   │ data: 3    │
 null   │ nextNode: ───► │ nextNode: ───► │ nextNode: ───► null
        └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
             ▲
 ┌───────────│─┐
 │ headNode: ┘ │
 └─────────────┘
        ↑
       list
```

Every time we arrive at the second statement in the loop's body, we'll have this invariant: `previous` - `current` - `next` reference successive nodes or are null.

Now a rewiring takes place with `current.nextNode = previous`. The current node's `nextNode` reference will no longer point to `next` but to `previous`:

```
previous  current            next
   ↓         ↓                ↓
        ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
        │ data: 1    │   │ data: 2    │   │ data: 3    │
 null ◄─── :nextNode │   │ nextNode: ───► │ nextNode: ───► null
        └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
             ▲
 ┌───────────│─┐
 │ headNode: ┘ │
 └─────────────┘
        ↑
       list
```

The last two statements of the loop body, and the first one in the next iteration, together shift the 3 node references to the right:

```
          previous         current            next
             ↓                ↓                ↓
        ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
        │ data: 1    │   │ data: 2    │   │ data: 3    │
 null ◄─── :nextNode │   │ nextNode: ───► │ nextNode: ───► null
        └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
             ▲
 ┌───────────│─┐
 │ headNode: ┘ │
 └─────────────┘
        ↑
       list
```

And again the `nextNode` member of `current` is redirected with `current.nextNode = previous`:

```
          previous         current            next
             ↓                ↓                ↓
        ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
        │ data: 1    │   │ data: 2    │   │ data: 3    │
 null ◄─── :nextNode │ ◄─── :nextNode │   │ nextNode: ───► null
        └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
             ▲
 ┌───────────│─┐
 │ headNode: ┘ │
 └─────────────┘
        ↑
       list
```

Another invariant to highlight: *after* that rewiring assignment, `current` is the head of a *reversed* list, while `next` is the head of the unaltered part of the list.

Again we iterate further, and perform the shift:

```
                           previous         current        next
                              ↓                ↓            ↓
        ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
        │ data: 1    │   │ data: 2    │   │ data: 3    │
 null ◄─── :nextNode │ ◄─── :nextNode │   │ nextNode: ───► null
        └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
             ▲
 ┌───────────│─┐
 │ headNode: ┘ │
 └─────────────┘
        ↑
       list
```

And again, `current.nextNode` is mutated to point "backwards":

```
                           previous         current        next
                              ↓                ↓            ↓
        ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
        │ data: 1    │   │ data: 2    │   │ data: 3    │
 null ◄─── :nextNode │ ◄─── :nextNode │ ◄─── :nextNode │   null
        └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
             ▲
 ┌───────────│─┐
 │ headNode: ┘ │
 └─────────────┘
        ↑
       list
```

At this point the reversal is complete, and we could in theory stop here, but two more instructions are executed in this last iteration of the loop, which shift 2 out of 3 references:

```
                                                         current
                                            previous       next
                                               ↓            ↓
        ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
        │ data: 1    │   │ data: 2    │   │ data: 3    │
 null ◄─── :nextNode │ ◄─── :nextNode │ ◄─── :nextNode │   null
        └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
             ▲
 ┌───────────│─┐
 │ headNode: ┘ │
 └─────────────┘
        ↑
       list
```

The loop condition is no longer true (cf `current`), and luckily we still have `previous` referencing the last node of the original list, which is now the head of the reversed list. So it is assigned to `list.headNode`. The function returns and its local variables are disposed:

```
        ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
        │ data: 1    │   │ data: 2    │   │ data: 3    │
 null ◄─── :nextNode │ ◄─── :nextNode │ ◄─── :nextNode │
        └────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
                                               ▲
 ┌─────────────┐                               │
 │ headNode: ──────────────────────────────────┘
 └─────────────┘
        ↑
       list
```

I hope this clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reverse a Linked List, you need to walk through all its Nodes and change the links between them in such a way so that for every Node, its previous Node becomes the next one.

```
[Node1] => [Node2] => [Node3] - initial list
        <-         <-         - new links
```

There are two actions need to be done at each iteration step:

- swap the link to the next Node of the current Node by assigning previous to it;
- advance forward by reassigning the `current` Node to the reference that has been initially stored in its `next` property, which would point either to a subsequent Node or `null` if the end of the List is reached.

Note that in order to be able to iterate through the list, the reference to the `current` Node at the **beginning** of each iteration should be **unchanged** (*otherwise you'll not be able to move forward*). Whilst it's being altered by swapping its link to the `next` Node changed, we're reassigning it to the reference pointing to the subsequent Node that has not been altered yet. And the cycle repeats.